# Byte offset notation for a 900 mb XML file

Tags: c++, xml, search-engine

I am building a search engine in c++ (using a 900 mb rapidXML file that contains pages from wikiBooks) and my objective is to parse the ~900 MB XML document using rapidXML so that the user can just enter one word in the search bar and receive the ACTUAL XML DOCUMENTS that contain that word (link).

I need to figure out how to store index of each token (aka each word within of each document) so that when the user wants to see the page numbers a certain word occurs, I can jump to that specific page.

I have been told to do the "file io offset" (where you store where in the file a word is so that you can jump to it) and I am having a hard time understanding what to do.

Questions:

1. Do I use the "seekg" and "tellg" in the istream library (to find the byte location that each document PAGE is stored at)? And if so, how?
2. How do I return the actual document back to the user (that contains many occurances of the searched word)?

Comment: Why not read the file into an appropriate data structure (trie, hash table, etc) and do the searches in memory?

Comment: That would be far too big though, wouldn't it? We're talking about 900 MB of data. I have already stored every word within the <text></text> brackets and their corresponding page ID numbers. How do I return the actual documents to the user?

Comment: Well seekg and tellg only work reliably on files opened in binary mode, not text mode.  There is no such thing as a "line" when you open a file in binary mode.  Second, http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/